# How to load a MODFLOW file that includes external file using ' OPEN/CLOSE' in FloPy? I got stuck with loading a UPW file

Tags: flopy

I am using FloPy to load an existing MODFLOW-NWT model. The UPW package relies on external files for hydraulic properties. I noticed that the UPW cannot be loaded with the regular loading command.

```
mf_old_nwt = flopy.modflow.Modflow.load('oakey03_tr.nam', 
                                        model_ws=loadpth, 
                                        version=version, 
                                        exe_name=exe_name,
                                        load_only=['UPW'])
```

I also tried to load the UPW separately, it still doesn't work. I cannot find an example for this in the repository.

```
upw_old = flopy.modflow.ModflowUpw.load(file_upw, mf_old_nwt, ext_unit_dict=ext_unit)
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet you need to load the DIS with UPW - the UPW load may need DIS  info.

Comment: Thanks, J. It turns out that there is an extra blank line in my upw file. MODFLOW doesn't complain about this, but FloPy will get stuck.